# How to add a Date Picker on my View on a MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am learning .NET MVC, I am having a bit of difficult on adding a Date Picker on my Views.

What I am trying to do is that I want to create my **Model** called Person.cs:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First name is required")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @using System.Web.Optimization
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("List", "ListPerson", "Person")</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

**BundleConfig.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace WebApplication1.App_Start
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {

        // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));
        }
    }
}
```

I am creating a View called **Create.chstml**, which it consist to create a new user.

```
    @model WebApplication1.Models.Person

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    }

    <h2>Create</h2> 

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Person</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "datepicker form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "ListPerson")
</div>

<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    <script>
        $(function() {
            $(".datepicker").datepicker(
                {
                    dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear : true
                });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Is there any simplest way to indicate on that it must popup a date-picker?

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker" } })
```

I have installed on the packet-nugget the **JQuery.UI.Combined**

Making some research I found this link:
https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

```
<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
</script>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Actually I don't know how to implement on my code.

I am trying to follow this link also:

https://forums.asp.net/t/2134739.aspx?How+to+add+datepicker+to+EditorFor+field+in+asp+net+mvc+5

**Solution found from this video**: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yuo2XX5_rYo

Comment: Double check your jQuery selector is correct on the line which initialize the jQuery plugin. Are you trying to enable datepicker for the input with Id attribute value `datepicker` ? What happens when you try `$( "#DateOfBirth" ).datepicker();` ?

Comment: I don't see any element `#datepicker` in your view.

Comment: I have corrected the element:
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker" } })

I am sure, missing something on the import, but don't know where...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is probably your jQuery selector:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
```

Currently this will find the HTML element with the `id` ***datepicker***. Looking at your HTML snippet, it will generate the input with the `id` ***DateOfBirth*** instead (double check what it looks like when you inspect element). Try:

```
$("#DateOfBirth").datepicker();
```

The better alternative would be to add a class `datepicker` (or similar) to your HTML element, then use that as the selector so it applies to all datepickers that you may wish to use in the future:

***View***

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker" } })
```

***Javascript***

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker();
```

I'd also look into how selectors work so you can better identify how to use them, for example if it's prefixed with `#` it will look for an element with that `id` attribute. If it's prefixed with `.` then it will look for all elements that have the class you specify.

Comment: Unfortunately is not working :s
As you can see on top, I installed the plugin, addedd on bundle and addedd the datpicker script.

I found a workaround, which work only on some browsers:
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }